# FileUpload.SaveAs() doesn't let my visual studio see the uploaded pictures hence my image control isn't showing the picture

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(~\resouces\cruises\cruise_cl\+ savedFileName));
```

And I've debugged to check maybe something's wrong with Parameter but nothing's wrong and I can the pictures with my windows explorer and I copy the path and past it in my browser and the image show up. but I still can't see it in the Solution Explorer and my Image Control doesn't see the picture either!!

I really have no idea what's going on .. any hints please ?!!

**Edit**

The problem was that I assigned an actual path to the ImageUrl property. I should have used a virtual path.

Thanks for trying to help

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please read this: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: I'm using the SaveAs methode .. it saves the picture and I can see when I open the folder with the windows explorer but when I open visual studio I can't see the picture in the solution explorer. I'm sorry but I don't know what else I can provide here in my question!

Comment: Where are you saving the picture? How are you trying to access it elsewhere? What errors/exceptions are you getting? Post the code.

Comment: Ok, resources is a folder in the main directory of my web application..I'm trying to access it with the ordinary windows explorer like My Computer>D>MyProject..I'm not getting any exceptions but the Image control won't see the picture! .. I hope I got your questions right .. and I'll post now the code that I use to assign the path to the Image control

Comment: Please _edit_ your question and add the details to it instead of in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is an option in the visual studio under "Project" menu item named "Show All Files" that will allow you to see all files and then you can write click on the file and include it in the project.

Comment: Yeah, If I added the picture manually I can see it in the solution explorer. but how can I do that programtically ?

Comment: You want to include a file in the visual studio application programtically ?! What are you trying to do ?!

Comment: hmmmm...then you are telling me that the image appears in the right path in the windows explorer and in the visual studio..but your Image Control ( assuming it is a user control ) can't see the image...in this case it will be a path problem in the image control that need to be updated.

Comment: you were right thank you .. I was setting the ImageUrl property to an actual path .. I assigned a virtual path and it worked (Y)